# Getting settings from configure activity

Tags: android, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

I need help with following situation. I have widget with configure activity. In the activity is spinner with some values, which should affect widget look (only text in one `TextView`). At this time, I set `AlarmManager` to widget update (service) and modify `TextView` in Configure activity. This works fine, but when I restart phone, alarm isn't set anymore and I should set It again. I can't do it, because settings from Configure activity is lost.

There is solution - save `AppWidgetID` with widget settings to database, but I think, it's not the best solution. A problem is, that `onUpdate` method of `AppWidgetProvider` is called before `onCreate` method of ConfigureActivity.

In brief, I need get some settings from Configure Activity, pass it to AppWidgetProvider and update widget.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `SharedPreferences`. Use your configure activity to set preference values and read them from your widget. Use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` to access the shared preferences.

Comment: SharedPreferences was my first idea how to resolve it. Saving is ok, but how can I say AppWidgetProvider that widget with specific AppWidgetId has to be updated?

Comment: @skywall - The mechanism for updating the widget from the configuration activity is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration). You retrieve the widget ID from the intent that launches the configuration activity.

Comment: Thanks, finally I've used SharedPreferences and onReceive method of AppWidgetProvider.

Answer (score 0):

What about a using [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)?
If you need to save some preference settings related to your application, you could use this solution.

Something like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String prefName = sharedPreference.getString(YOUR_PREF_NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE);
```